# list all Input fields generated dynamically on django

Tags: django

I have a problem that I want to solve when I add many Input dynamic for example five input

How do I know to list all Input fields generated dynamically on django knowing that I get one field by name only

```
date=form.cleaned_data.get('date')
```

The problem is illustrated in the following form:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using django forms, you can use the [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) to distinguish them.

For example, if you have 5 equal forms:

```
 for i in xrange(5):
        form = FormExample(data=data, prefix=i)
        date=form.cleaned_data.get('date')
```

As an alternative you can use formsets, you can learn more about them in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Can you provide an example how to use the `prefix` in OP's question?